# How can I perform automation on a closed Shadow Root element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, shadow-root

I am trying to write automation for a web driver using Selenium. With an shadow-root (open) element, I can use JS path to interact with it. However, if the element has a shadow-root (closed), I cannot do it in the same way.

How should I handle shadow-root (closed) element?

[image]

Comment: You can not, it does its job, it is closed

Comment: See if this answer helps, this is as close as you can get with dealing `shadow-root(close)` elements in selenium - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053412/7598774

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242284/how-to-locate-element-in-shadow-root-closed-host